# Is it possible to rent Azure disk and connect to them via iSCSI from my PC?

Tags: azure, disk

I need to rent one disk (SSD and HDD) and make them shared disk so I can connect to them via iSCSI so I can make my SQL database for testing purpose.
Can I just buy the disk space I want on Azure or are those disks **only** for Azure VMs?

I want those disks to be accessible locally, like any other iSCSI disk - not via web interface or anything like that.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

No.  Azure Disks can't be mounted over iSCSI.  You can have an [Azure Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction) share and store your databases there.  Or if this is SQL Server you can store database files [directly on Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/sql-server-data-files-in-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other Microsoft solution that offers iSCSI shared disks? @David

Comment: Nothing that would be better than simply testing using an Azure Virtual Machine.  IE there are solutions where you provision an Azure VM that publishes an iSCSI endpoint, but that wouldn't really be sensible or cost-effective for testing. eg https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/netapp.netapp-ontap-cloud?tab=PlansAndPrice